# Shortened syntax wastes memory?

Tags: javascript, optimization, complexity-theory

I found that a neat way to convert an array-like object (e.g. NodeList, Arguments) into a real array is to use:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(...);
```

Then, I thought of a way to shorten this syntax:

```
[].slice.call(...);
```

Would the latter method waste time and/or memory by creating a new array each time that it is called? Should I avoid this syntax in complexity-essential applications, or do JavaScript engines optimise this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think the `[]` notation probably should be avoided. If you want to save space, why not just do:

```
// Once in JS
var slice = Array.prototype.slice.call;

// Many places in JS
slice(...);
```

Comment: There's a slight quirk about your solution; doing this makes `slice` return `window` because of some sort of contextual error. It might work better to do something like `function slice(a) { return Array.prototype.slice.call(a); }`

Comment: Really? Perhaps your right, I didn't test it. I was mainly just trying to get my point across.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't see a major problem with using your shortened syntax.  Any performance impact would be minimal (and some engines will optimise accordingly anyway) so it boils down to a personal preference.  There are a couple of alternatives available to you, though.  For example, you could use the ECMAScript 5th edition `Function.prototype.bind` to shorten it to anything you want:

```
var sl = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);
var myArr = sl([1, 2, 3], 1);
//-> [ 2, 3 ]
```

And of course, `bind` [can be implemented in unsupporting browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility).

In supported browsers/environments, you might also be able to use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for achieving the same results:

```
// Array.from works with any iterable or array-like object
var myArr = Array.from(arrayLike);

// Spread operator works only with iterables:
var myArr = [ ...arrayLike ];
```

If you're using a transpiler such as Traceur or Babel, these are already supported.

Comment: Great tip! I would upvote, but I've hit my vote limit for now.

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);` is the long way to binding a context to the `call` method of the function prototype.
Should be `var sl = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);`

Comment: @bm_i: you're right, of course.  I've updated along with a couple of newer options for ES 2015.